# Add items to property as a List of Strings

Tags: vb.net

I have a property defined as a list of integers:

```
Public Property lista_consultas_registros_cambio_clasificacion() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return insideQueries_representaciones_clasificacion_diferente
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of String))
            insideQueries_representaciones_clasificacion_diferente = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

I tried to add an item using:

```
Catalogo_Rep.lista_consultas_registros_cambio_clasificacion.Add("Text")
```

and i get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException:object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your internal field `insideQueries_representaciones_clasificacion_diferente` has not been initialized.

You need to initialize it in the constructor.

```
insideQueries_representaciones_clasificacion_diferente = new List(of String)
```

Technically you don't need to initialize it in the constructor as long as it is initialized before use.  But generally when it is a property of an object you will want to initialize it in the constructor.